# Different intensity values for same image in OpenCV and MATLAB

Tags: matlab, python-2.7, opencv, image-processing

I'm using Python 2.7 and OpenCV 3.x for my project for omr sheet evaluation using web camera.

While finding the number of white pixels in around the center of circle,I came to know that the intensity values are wrong, but it shows the correct values in MATLAB when I'm using imtool('a1.png').

I'm using .png image (datatype uint8).
just run the code and in the image go to [360:370,162:172] coordinate and see the intensity values.. it should not be 0.
find the images here -> [a1.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcFjD.png) [a2.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z732X.png)

Why is this happening?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
#select radius of circle
radius = 10;
#function for finding white pixels
def thresh_circle(img,ptx,pty):
    centerX = ptx;
    centerY = pty;
    cntOfWhite = 0;
    for i in range((centerX - radius),(centerX + radius)):
        for j in range((centerY - radius), (centerY + radius)):
            if(j < img.shape[0] and i < img.shape[1]):
                val = img[i][j]
                if (val == 255):
                    cntOfWhite = cntOfWhite + 1;
    return cntOfWhite

MIN_MATCH_COUNT = 10
img1 = cv2.imread('a1.png',0) # queryImage
img2 = cv2.imread('a2.png',0) # trainImage
sift = cv2.SIFT()# Initiate SIFT detector
kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1,None)# find the keypoints and descriptors with SIFT
kp2, des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(img2,None)
FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 0
index_params = dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees = 5)
search_params = dict(checks = 50)
flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)
matches = flann.knnMatch(des1,des2,k=2)
good = []# store all the good matches as per Lowe's ratio test.
for m,n in matches:
    if m.distance < 0.7*n.distance:
        good.append(m)

if len(good)>MIN_MATCH_COUNT:
    src_pts = np.float32([ kp1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
    dst_pts = np.float32([ kp2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good ]).reshape(-1,1,2)

    M, mask = cv2.findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts, cv2.LMEDS,5.0)
    #print M
    matchesMask = mask.ravel().tolist()

    h,w = img1.shape
else:
    print "Not enough matches are found - %d/%d" % (len(good),MIN_MATCH_COUNT)
    matchesMask = None

img3 = cv2.warpPerspective(img1, M, (img2.shape[1],img2.shape[0]))
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img3,(5,5),0)
ret3,th3 = cv2.threshold(blur,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
ret,th2 = cv2.threshold(blur,ret3,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
print th2[360:370,162:172]#print a block of image
plt.imshow(th2, 'gray'),plt.show()
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.imwrite('th2.png',th2)
ptyc = np.array([170,200,230,260]);#y coordinates of circle center
ptxc = np.array([110,145,180,215,335,370,405,440])#x coordinates of circle center
pts_src = np.zeros(shape = (32,2),dtype=np.int);#x,y coordinates of circle center
ct = 0;
for i in range(0,4):
    for j in range(0,8):
        pts_src[ct][1] = ptyc[i];
        pts_src[ct][0] = ptxc[j];
        ct = ct+1;
boolval = np.zeros(shape=(8,4),dtype=np.bool)
ct = 0;
for j in range(0,8):
    for i in range(0,4):
        a1 = thresh_circle(th2,pts_src[ct][0],pts_src[ct][1])
        ct = ct+1;
        if(a1 > 50):
            boolval[j][i] = 1
        else:
            boolval[j][i] = 0
```

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: @miki wrong means different values

Comment: How much different? If it's almost the same value it's due to the different codec used (this is true for jpeg... probably also for  png). Otherwise there are errors in your code ;D

Comment: its totally different ..cz after thresholding  the white pixel intensity is shown 0..while in matlab its 255

Comment: http://ideone.com/p3t5tM  this is the code so far

Comment: So it's not a problem with images, but with your code. Please edit the **relevant** code into the question, both Python and Matlab. See how to do a [mcve]

Comment: If the images are PNG, they are lossless and so both of the images when decoded should produce the same intensities / RGB values.  Please provide all of the code you used to reproduce the error.

Comment: can anyone suggest the various reasons why it happens in general ?